# Build errors with Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

I have an old project developed with Angular 13.2.5 using VS Code. To build it I installed the last versions of Angular and NodeJs but I have errors building it. With Angular 13.2.5 I get a warning that it doesn't support NodeJs 20.x.x. After I installed a compatible version of NodeJs I get the following errors:

[image]

The Angular version now is the following:

[image]

Any help please ?